# How can I get Eclipse to completely ignore node_modules?

Tags: eclipse

I have an Eclipse 4.14 project with a node_modules directory in it. I both marked node_modules as "Derived" and included it in the "Resource Filters" for the project. Now Eclipse doesn't show it or search it--good--but if I refresh the project in the package explorer it still takes forever. And doing an `npm install` shows Eclipse taking a significant chunk of the CPU the whole time and is much slower when Eclipse is running. So while Eclipse is ignoring the directory in most ways, it still seems to be doing a lot of unneeded processing on it. Is there a better way to hide node_modules from Eclipse?

Comment: Hello. Did you solve this? Experiencing the same issue.